# Loading text strings from XML omits a few characters randomly

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, character

I am a newbie to flash. I implement some application with Flash CS6.
I found very attractive gallery template from [here](http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_203_carousel).
In this, flash loads text string from xml file and shows this text when user put a cursor on the corresponding thumbnail image.
 When i download the source file package and open swf file, It looks fine. when I put a cursor on a thumbnail image it shows a matching text string from the xml file like following.

---

Item No. 9 (194 circular gallery)

### Circular Photo Gallery, Flash ActionScript 3.0 XML, rotating thumbnails, fade in/out transitions using Tweener.

But when I open fla file and publish it to .exe file or export to .swf video file, it omits some characters when loading same text string like this.

---

tem o  irular galler

### ircular hoto aller Flash ActionScript 3.0 XML, rotating thumbnails, fade inout transitions using eener.

patterns of omitting the characters even looks random. 
is there anybody who experienced same problem?
(the source looks written in CS5. now I am trying publish it in CS5 version and check it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is not about xml loading.

I recommend you to play with text field properties. If you have static text in you fla compiled swf will contain only symbols from default text. 
E.g. if default text is 'test' you will see only t,e,s symbols.

Comment: Thanks! After embedding font for all characters as your answer, it displays all the texts beautifuly. (It is on Text > Embedding font tab.)